# A tax calculator application to calculate tax and print final receipt

Tags: java, object-oriented, interview-questions, calculator

Although this question has been asked a lot of times, I was hoping for a feedback on my approach.

> Tax Calculator Basic sales tax is applicable at a rate of 10% on all
>   goods, except books, food, and medical products that are exempt.
>   Import duty is an additional sales tax applicable on all imported
>   goods at a rate of 5%, with no exemptions.
>
> When I purchase items I receive a receipt which lists the name of all
>   the items and their price (including tax), finishing with the total
>   cost of the items, and the total amounts of sales taxes paid. The
>   rounding rules for sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf
>   price of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of
>   sales tax.
>
> Write an application that prints out the receipt details ...
>
> Input 1:
>
> ```
> 1 book at 12.49  
> 1 music CD at 14.99   
> 1 chocolate bar at 0.85
> ```
>
> Output 1:
>
> ```
> 1 book: 12.49  
> 1 music CD: 16.49  
> 1 chocolate bar: 0.85
> Sales Taxes: 1.50   
> Total: 29.83
> ```
>
> Input 2:
>
> ```
> 1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00  
> 1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50
> ```
>
> Output 2:
>
> ```
> 1 imported box of chocolates: 10.50  
> 1 imported bottle of perfume: 54.65  
> Sales Taxes: 7.65  
> Total: 65.15
> ```
>
> Input 3:
>
> ```
> 1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99  
> 1 bottle of perfume at 18.99  
> 1 packet of headache pills at 9.75  
> 1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25
> ```
>
> Output 3:
>
> ```
> 1 imported bottle of perfume: 32.19  
> 1 bottle of perfume: 20.89  
> 1 packet of headache pills: 9.75  
> 1 imported box of chocolates: 11.85  
> Sales Taxes: 6.70  
> Total: 74.68
> ```

**TaxCalculatorApplication**

```java
class TaxCalculatorApplication {

    Receipt generateReceipt(String[] inputs) {
        List<Item> items = ItemFactory.from(inputs);
        return new Receipt(items);
    }
}
```

**ItemFactory**

```java
public class ItemFactory {

    public static List<Item> from(String[] inputs) {
        return Arrays.stream(inputs)
                .map(ItemFactory::from)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Item from(String input) {
        Item item = ItemAdapter.createItemFromString(input);
        ItemTaxCalculator.applyTaxes(item);
        return item;
    }

}
```

**ItemAdapter**

```java
public class ItemAdapter {
    private static final String ITEM_ENTRY_REGEX = "(\\d+) ([\\w\\s]* )at (\\d+.\\d{2})";

    public static Item createItemFromString(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ITEM_ENTRY_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        matcher.find();

        return new Item(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

**ItemTaxCalculator**

```java
public class ItemTaxCalculator {
    private static final double SALES_TAX_PERCENT = 0.1;
    private static final double ADDITIONAL_SALES_TAX_PERCENT = 0.05;

    public static void applyTaxes(Item item) {
        if (!item.isExempted()) {
            item.setBasicSalesTaxAmount(SALES_TAX_PERCENT);
        }

        if (item.isImported()) {
            item.setAdditionalSalesTax(ADDITIONAL_SALES_TAX_PERCENT);
        }
    }
}
```

**Receipt**

```java
public class Receipt {
    private double totalSalesTax = 0.0;
    private double totalAmount = 0.0;
    private String itemDetails;

    public Receipt(List<Item> items) {

        StringBuilder itemDetails = new StringBuilder();

        for (Item item : items) {
            itemDetails.append(item.toString()).append("\n");
            totalSalesTax += item.getTaxAmount();
            totalAmount += item.getFinalPrice();
        }
        totalAmount = MathUtils.roundOffAmount(totalAmount);
        totalSalesTax = MathUtils.roundOffAmount(totalSalesTax);

        this.itemDetails = itemDetails.toString();
    }

    public double getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public double getTotalSalesTax() {
        return totalSalesTax;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Receipt" + "\n"
                + itemDetails
                + "Sales Taxes: " + totalSalesTax + "\n"
                + "Total: " + totalAmount
                +"\n*******************************\n";
    }
}
```

**Item**

```java
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double basePrice;
    private double basicSalesTaxAmount;
    private double additionalSalesTaxAmount;

    public Item(String quantity, String name, String basePrice) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = Integer.valueOf(quantity);
        this.basePrice = Double.valueOf(basePrice);
    }

    public double getFinalPrice() {
        return MathUtils.roundOffAmount(quantity * basePrice + getTaxAmount());
    }

    public double getTaxAmount() {
        return quantity * (basicSalesTaxAmount + additionalSalesTaxAmount);
    }

    public boolean isImported() {
        return name.contains("imported");
    }

    public boolean isExempted() {
        return Stream.of("book", "chocolate", "pill")
                .anyMatch(exemptedItem -> name.contains(exemptedItem));
    }

    public void setBasicSalesTaxAmount(double factor) {
        basicSalesTaxAmount = basePrice * factor;
    }

    public void setAdditionalSalesTax(double additionalSalesTaxPercent) {
        additionalSalesTaxAmount = MathUtils.roundOffTax(basePrice * additionalSalesTaxPercent);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(quantity) +
                " " +
                name +
                " : " +
                getFinalPrice();
    }
}
```

**MathUtils**

```java
public class MathUtils {

    public static double roundOffTax(double number) {
        return Math.ceil(number * 20) / 20;
    }

    public static double roundOffAmount(double number) {
        return Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;
    }
}
```

The whole project is available at [this link](https://github.com/ankitprahladsoni/tax_calculator/tree/bf1da78d3d513c5b24149142e1e2de8d97fa4a3a).

Comment: Obvious hole is the categorization of items.  Items which erroneously get tax exempt status include “bookmarks” and “pillows”, and “chocolate flavoured lipstick”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't mix `Item` class with `Recipe`(`ShoppingCart`) class. the `quantity` should be part of `RecipeItem`(`ShoppingCartItem`), as well as `Tax`&`Cost`. The `TotalTax`&`TotalCost` should be part of `ShoppingCart`.

My `Item` class, has only `Name`&`Price` & some readonly properties(getters) like `IsImported` (in c#):

```
class Product
{
    static readonly IDictionary<ProductType, string[]> productType_Identifiers = 
        new Dictionary<ProductType, string[]>
        {
            {ProductType.Food, new[]{ "chocolate", "chocolates" }},
            {ProductType.Medical, new[]{ "pills" }},
            {ProductType.Book, new[]{ "book" }}
        };

    public decimal ShelfPrice { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsImported { get { return Name.Contains("imported "); } }

    public bool IsOf(ProductType productType)
    {
        return productType_Identifiers.ContainsKey(productType) &&
            productType_Identifiers[productType].Any(x => Name.Contains(x));
    }
}

class ShoppringCart
{
    public IList<ShoppringCartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalTax { get { return CartItems.Sum(x => x.Tax); } }

    public decimal TotalCost { get { return CartItems.Sum(x => x.Cost); } }
}

class ShoppringCartItem
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Tax { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get { return Quantity * (Tax + Product.ShelfPrice); } }
}
```

Your tax calculation part is coupled with `Item`. An item doesn't define tax policies it's Government's job. Based on the problem's description, there are two kind of Sales Taxes: `Basic` and `Duty` taxes. You can use [`Template Method Design Pattern`](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3199484/c-sharp/how-to-implement-the-template-method-design-pattern-in-c.html) to implement it:

```
abstract class SalesTax
{
    abstract public bool IsApplicable(Product item);
    abstract public decimal Rate { get; }

    public decimal Calculate(Product item)
    {
        if (IsApplicable(item))
        {
            //sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf price of p contains (np/100)
            var tax = (item.ShelfPrice * Rate) / 100;

            //The rounding rules: rounded up to the nearest 0.05
            tax = Math.Ceiling(tax / 0.05m) * 0.05m;

            return tax;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

class BasicSalesTax : SalesTax
{
    private ProductType[] _taxExcemptions = new[] 
    { 
        ProductType.Food, ProductType.Medical, ProductType.Book 
    };

    public override bool IsApplicable(Product item)
    {
        return !(_taxExcemptions.Any(x => item.IsOf(x)));
    }

    public override decimal Rate { get { return 10.00M; } }
}

class ImportedDutySalesTax : SalesTax
{
    public override bool IsApplicable(Product item)
    {
        return item.IsImported;
    }

    public override decimal Rate { get { return 5.00M; } }
}
```

And finally a class to apply taxes:

```
class TaxCalculator
{
    private SalesTax[] _Taxes = new SalesTax[] { new BasicSalesTax(), new ImportedDutySalesTax() };

    public void Calculate(ShoppringCart shoppringCart)
    {
        foreach (var cartItem in shoppringCart.CartItems)
        {
            cartItem.Tax = _Taxes.Sum(x => x.Calculate(cartItem.Product));
        }

    }
}
```

You can try them out at [MyFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zz6Jp4).

Comment: This is great. Thank you for pointing out the obvious points that I completely missed. :)

Comment: it's my pleasure :)